# Nodemon restart run gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have the following code in my gulpfile

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.browserify)
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
        .pipe(refresh(server));
});

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: 'app.js'
    });
});
```

I need to run the scripts and lint tasks when Nodemon restarts.I have the following

```
gulp.task('nodemon', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: 'app.js'
    }).on('restart', function () {
        gulp.run(['scripts', 'lint']);
    });
});
```

Gulp.run() is now deprecated, so how would I achieve the above using gulp and best practices?

Comment: Please add a comment if you are going to down-vote my question as to why you think this question is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe the down-voter thinks it should be clear from the doc, but indeed, (s)he should make his reasons clear.

Comment: It's, however, not clear in the docs.

Comment: A gulp-nodemon wrapper that restarts your app as you develop, and keeps your build system contained to one process. See this [gulp-nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon)

Comment: Gotta hate frivolous downvoters. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gulp-nodemon documentation states that you can do it directly, passing an array of tasks to execute:

```
nodemon({script: 'app.js'}).on('restart', ['scripts', 'lint']);
```

See [doc here](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon#nodemononevent-tasks)

UPDATE, as the author of gulp-nodemon uses run as well:

Idea #1, use functions:

```
var browserifier = function () {
  gulp.src(paths.browserify)
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
    .pipe(refresh(server));
});

gulp.task('scripts', browserifier);

var linter = function () {
  gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});

gulp.task('lint', linter);

nodemon({script: 'app.js'}).on('restart', function(){
  linter();
  browserifier();
});
```

Comment: Ya I saw this with [gulp-nodemon](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/blob/master/index.js). If you click on the link you will be able to tell that the author is using the deprecated gulp.run() method as well? I can do everything I want with nodemon without having to use gulp-nodemon.

Comment: Added a suggestion then, using regular functions (idea came up in gulp discussion around "run" deprecation).

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use Mangled Deutz's suggestion about using functions.  That's the best, most guaranteed way to make sure this works now and going forward.

However, functions won't help if you need to run dependent tasks or a series of tasks.  I wrote [run-sequence](https://npmjs.org/package/run-sequence) to fix this.  It doesn't rely on `gulp.run`, and it's able to run a bunch of tasks in order.

Comment: Looks very interesting and will definitely give it a try. I have been looking for a way to run tasks in order.